# Can I combine the spread / struct update syntax with to_owned()?

Tags: rust

I love that you can replace something like

```
Doc {
  id: 1,
  a: new_doc.a,
  b: new_doc.b,
  c: new_doc.c,
  d: new_doc.d,
  e: new_doc.e,
};
```

with

```
Doc {
  id: 1,
  ..new_doc
};
```

But can you do the same with this:

```
Doc {
  id: 1,
  a: new_doc.a.to_owned(),
  b: new_doc.b.to_owned(),
  c: new_doc.c.to_owned(),
  d: new_doc.d.to_owned(),
  e: new_doc.e.to_owned(),
};
```

If not, what would be the shortest way to write that?

Comment: `.to_owned()` does not give the same type unless it's really `.clone()`.

Comment: And the shortest way to write this is as you wrote this.

Comment: thus, `a, b, c, d, e` maybe your could use an array.

Comment: You could give `Doc` its own method that clones itself with owned data (I'll call it `clone_as_owned`), then you can at least hide the mess in that method, and do `Doc { id: 1, ..(new_doc.clone_as_owned()) }` elsewhere.

Comment: If what you want is to clone each field of the source record, then you can a) `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` on `Doc`, 2) do `Doc { id: 1, ..new_doc.clone() }`. A bit inefficient, but brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if you do not want to lose ownership of the original struct, the solution would be to clone it (or implement `ToOwned` if you may prefer, although `clone` is more correct IMO):

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Doc {
    id: usize, 
    a: String,
}

fn main() {
    let d = Doc {id: 1, a: "foo".to_string()};
    let d2 = Doc {
        id: 2,
        ..d.clone()
    };
    
    println!("{d:?} {d2:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f5d39d8077d217f6bf8851adb91693ad)

Comment: Is there also a way if `new_doc`/`d` is of type `Json<Doc>`?

Comment: @leonheess, I think you may be interested in the `From` and `Into` traits instead. Check it out in the docs. (I don't know about which `Json` type you are refering)

Comment: `serde::json::Json`, I also added the full code :)

Comment: @leonheess, you shouldn't edit questions to add more problems. Instead consider open newly related questions. Or, add the full information when posting the original questions :)

Comment: If you could just tell me if your solution is still possible if the type is `serde::json::Json<Doc>` instead of `Doc`, I'll be on my merry way

Comment: @leonheess, you cannot unpack different types that way. So I do not think is possible.